# Calculating a circles radius from two known points on its circumference

Tags: circles

For a simulation, I need to be able to calculate the radius $r$ of a circle $C$, knowing only two points on its circumference, $P_1$ and $P_2$, as well as the distance between them ($a$) and how much of the whole circumference $c$ is in the arc between those two points ($\frac{c}{x}$, where $x$ is known and $\geq 1$). Neither the arc itself nor its angle is known, but the arc should be equal to $\frac{2\pi r}{x}$.

The following image should illustrate this:

[image: example of a circle, $P_1$, $P_2$, $a$ and $x$ are known]

While being closely related to questions just as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285866/calculating-circle-radius-from-two-points-on-circumference-for-game-movement), it's not quite the same, as I don't know the angles.

Should this not be possible, what else would I need? Would a third point suffice?

Comment: You're missing one thing: which way is the arc curving? In your diagram you could have the center directly below $p_1$ (as shown), or directly above $p_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that the arclength $s$ between the two points is given by $s = 2\pi r/x$, where $x$ is known. So, we know the angle $\alpha$ of the arc between the two points -- it's just $\alpha = s/r = 2\pi/x$. Then, using the formula from the first answer, we have:

$$r \sin\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) = \frac{a}{2} $$

and so

$$r = \frac{\tfrac{1}{2}a} {\sin\tfrac{1}{2}\alpha } = \tfrac{1}{2}a\,\mathrm{cosec}\tfrac{1}{2}\alpha $$

Or, in summary

$$r = \frac{1}{2}a\,\mathrm{cosec}\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)$$

Comment: I added an additional sentence about the arc in the question. The arc itself is not known, only the distance between the two points, but it is known that the arc equals $\frac{2\pi r}{x}$ with $x$ being known.

Comment: @Big-Blue, then you know $arc \over circumference$. The needed formula is in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing a formula that is usable on-the-fly! But somehow, the results I get with this are far off. [This circle](http://i.imgur.com/bt2q2sR.png) has a radius of $5$, but letting [WolframAlpha calculate the radius using the formula you provided](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29*7.071067811865476*csc%28%281%2F2%29*%281%2F4%29%29), I get a result around 28, which resembles the circumference.

Comment: Tell us the $P_1$, $P_2$, and $x$ that you used in your example test.

Comment: $P_1 = [0,5]$, $P_2 = [5,0]$, $x = 4$

Comment: My formula for \alpha was wrong. My apologies. So, in your example, $\alpha = 2\pi/4 = \pi/2$, and everything else should work.

Comment: Your picture shows $\alpha = 1/4$, which is not correct.

Comment: Thanks, with the correct $\alpha$, everything works as intended.

Comment: I'm sorry to dig this up again, but I tried using this formula again on a [circle with a higher radius](http://i.imgur.com/wkbahS5.png) and it was way off. This circle has $r = 220$, $B = [220,0]$, $B' = [190.53,110]$, $x = 12$ and $a = 113.87\ldots$. But while giving me the correct radius for the circle with the radius $5$, using it on this circle gets me $58.94\ldots$, which is _way_ different from the desired $220$. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: $\sin(\pi/12) = 0.259$, so $\cosec(\pi/12) = 3.864$. Multiply this by $a/2$, which is 56.9, and you get 220.

Comment: I'm very sorry, this was indeed an error in my implementation, as I implemented $\csc(x)$ as $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, which works as intended for $r=5$.

Answer (score 0):

Law of cosines:
$a^2 = 2R^{2}(1-2cos(\alpha))$, where $\alpha$ is the angle measure of an arc, and $a$ is the distance between points. $\alpha = 2\pi ({arc \over circumference})$.

Also $R \cdot sin({\alpha \over 2}) = {a \over 2}$, it is also pretty obviously.

If you only know $arc$ and $distance$, then $distance = (2R)\cdot sin({arc \over (2R)})$. The inverse function of $sin(x)/x$ you need here can be sure approximated.

Comment: Assuming that your $R$ is the radius, one can calculate $R=\frac{1}{2}*a*csc(\frac{a}{2})$ to obtain it, correct?

Comment: @Big-Blue Sure.